# Can I use the word "Gamma" instead of "rc" in semantic versioning?

Tags: semantic-versioning

Since `rc` (aka release candidate) comes after `beta`, can I call it `gamma` instead? (because `gamma` comes after `beta`)

Here's an example : 
Original : `v1.2.3-rc.2`
Modified : `v1.2.3-gamma.2`

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphens [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Numeric identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes. Pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version. A pre-release version indicates that the version is unstable and might not satisfy the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated normal version. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7, 1.0.0-x.7.z.92, 1.0.0-x-y-z.–.

So yes, they may be any string if it follows the above rules. Keep in mind that they are sorted alphabetically.

https://semver.org/